# ¿Cómo defino en Awk un delimitador consistente en más de un carácter?

Tags: linux, unix, awk, procesamiento-de-texto

Estoy utilizando Awk para poder separar un conjunto de registros que vienen en un fichero csv y necesito especificamente realizar la separación por 2 caracteres `@|`, el problema radica en que el parámetro `FS` al parecer separa solo por un caracter `@`,

```
 awk 'BEGIN{FS="@|"}{if(NF!=4){print NF $0}}' archivo.csv>>malos.bad
```

mi archivo es del estilo

```
aaaa@|aaaaa@|correo@correo.com@|ccccccc
```

(lo pueden guardar como archivo.csv)

y si se fijan existe un correo intermedio.

Lo lógico es que la cantidad de campos devuelta sea 4, pero el retorno es 5, porque como indiqué al parecer el FS separa solo por un campo y no por la combinación de ambos, el @ del correo lo toma como separador.

Estas son mis 2 premisas:

1. no tengo la oportunidad de modificar el archivo
2. debo separarlo por la combinación de ambos campos

¿Existe alguna manera de realizarlo a través de awk?

Answer (score 2):

Después de buscar en varios foros la respuesta, me encontré con esto:

```
awk -F '\\@\\|' '{print NF; exit}' <<< "aaaa@|bbbb@|cccc@|correo@email.com@|ddddd@|eeeee|ffffff"
```

para poder realizar el conteo de campos separados específicamente por `@|`, en el delimitador se le agregan los `\\`  a cada carácter.

Al realizar la prueba en Linux me da la respuesta que quiero, que en el caso del ejemplo es 6, lo que es correcto, de igual forma puedo agregar la concatenacion de caracteres de separacion que yo quiera.

Comment: O sea, sí se escapaba con dos baclslashes como te decía en la última edición :P Hablando en serio, me alegra que te funcione tu script. Las expresiones regulares son magia oscura pero lo sacan a uno de muchos líos

Comment: ahi cambie a como es correctamente

Comment: Recuerda que puedes marcar tu respuesta como aceptada para que otros sepan cual es la solución a esta pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Los delimitadores en awk y [gawk](/questions/tagged/gawk) pueden ser:

- Un caracter
- Una expresión regular

El pipe tiene líos al incluirse. Hay que escaparlo.

`awk 'BEGIN{FS="@\\|"}{if(NF!=4){print NF $0}}' prueba.csv > malos.bad`

Otra opción que uses gawk en vez de [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) por si la definición es más simple.

Algo como  `gawk -F'@\\|' 'BEGIN{ if(NF!=4) {print NF $0} }' prueba.csv > malos.bad` podría ser el camino. Escapando el pipe.

Referencia: [respuesta en SO original](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18536045/236345)

Comment: he revisado el link que aparece adjunto.. y traté de hacer algo similar pero no retorna lo que espero ejemplo: **echo "hello|@my|@friend@aaaa.com" | gawk -F'|@' '{print NF}'** debiese retornar 3, sin embargo retorna 4

Comment: Edité la respuesta para el caso específico del caracter que quieres usar.

Comment: asi no me fncionó.. debe ser doble back slash por cada caracter, en la respuesta veo 3..